# Mysql Count Distinct with Where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a count of Ids using some conditions.

This is my initial Query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT (id))
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    app_id = 1
        AND zone_id != 1
        AND presence_time_secs > 20
        AND initial_timestamp BETWEEN '2017-05-02 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-05 00:00:00'
group by 
    day(initial_timestamp)
```

So my problem is that is not getting the `zone_id!=1` part.

There are a few values when I do the same query using `zone_id=1`, but if in the first query i take the `zone_id!=1`it will return exactly the same values.

What am I doing wrong?

(I have also tried using NOT IN, same results).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the `zone_id!=1` count is as same as `zone_id=1` count.

Comment: But... the zone_id!=1 should take away the results from the other zones correct?

Comment: Try to count without `AND zone_id != 1` and see the result. I think you should query all the result without aggregation to confirm if data is correct or not.

Comment: Try to see values in this way:`SELECT ZONE_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT(Id)) AS RC
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE  app_id = 1
       /* AND zone_id != 1 */
        AND presence_time_secs > 20
        AND initial_timestamp BETWEEN '2017-05-02 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-05 00:00:00'
group by day(initial_timestamp) , ZONE_ID`

Comment: You're grouping by day so if there are any days that are not zone 1 they will be counted once. I think you're getting 3 each time (though it's hard to guess without any sample data)?

Answer (score 1):

Modify this `zone_id !=1` with `zone_id <> 1` or `zone_id NOT LIKE '1'`

Comment: tried it but returns the same... at the end i made another select inside the NOT IN and returns different data...